# How do I make it more concise? (not supposed to be hard)

Tags: java, list, nodes

Hi :) I'm pretty new to java and I can't find a solution... 
I have this code, and it's very repetitive and I need to repeat the process several times. can I do it using some kind of loop to make it more concise?

```
    System.out.println("enter grade 1:");
    Node node1 = new Node(x.nextInt());
    Node head = node1;

    System.out.println("enter grade 2:");
    Node node2 = new Node(x.nextInt());
    node2.next = head;
    head = node2;

    System.out.println("enter grade 3:");
    Node node3 = new Node(x.nextInt());
    node3.next = head;
    head = node3;
```

Comment: Yes you can. Do you need to repeat only three times?

Comment: Use a loop.....

Comment: More than three, around 7-8. And I tried using for loop but it got confusing. If you can show me I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: In other words, do you know the number of times you need to repeat?

Comment: ah ok. let's say 8 (i know what you mean, there is a fixed number I just need to check, so 8 for now is good)

Answer (score 1):

Just use a loop like this

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    Node head;
    int index = 0;

    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        System.out.println("enter grade " + (++index) + ":");
        Node node = new Node(scanner.nextInt());
        node.next = head;
        head = node;
    }
```

Comment: @kitten actually this is a good answer. Just change the while loop to for(int index = 0; index < 8; index++) and remove the index assignment. If you don't know how many ints there will be, keep it as is.

Answer (score 0):

This code might work for you :

```
public class Node {

    int grade ;
    Node next=null;

    Node(int grade){
        this.grade=grade;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        Node head =null;
        int index = 1;
        int gradeCount = 8;
        do {
            System.out.println("enter grade " + (index++) + ":");
            Node node = new Node(scanner.nextInt());
            node.next = head;
            head = node;
        }
        while(index!=gradeCount+1);

    }

}
```

Here I used a do while loop , this loop is exited until the `index` variable reaches `8`.